# Read file from remote server completely to local machine in python SSHCLient?

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, sftp, file-copying

My problem is that file differs in size anywhere from 1000 lines to 10000 lines and the below method doesn't work as it copies only a few lines and closes

```
client = SSHClient()
        client.load_system_host_keys()
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        client.connect(drasclientip, username=def_users[i], key_filename=pem_file)
        sftp = client.open_sftp()
        time.sleep(10)
        sftp.get(remote_file, file_dst,None)
        time.sleep(20)
        sftp.close()
        client.close()
```

I am only interested in the remote serves file which has some text at the end of the file.

I am thinking 2 ways  - either make the file transfer faster and efficient
or read  the remote file in reverse - that way I can get the end results at least

above code I put delays and it works something.

Comment: Can you download complete file anyhow? Using any GUI/commandline SFTP client running on the same machine as your Python code?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes i can download without any issue, this issue only happens when i try to run same code in ubuntu aws instance(jenkins slave machine)

Comment: Sorry that's rather ambiguous answer. Can you download the complete file using any GUI/commandline in the *"ubuntu aws instance"*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what worked for me.

1. since the file was too big to read via ssh client from remote server and I was only looking for file completion indication, which i can see only at EOF.
2. my startegy was to connect to remote server and run 'tac' linux command- which reverse the file and then i accessed the reversed file and found the EOF results in beginning of file and i was able to confirm the Validation of file

code:

*SSH client connect to remote server

```
ssh.exec("tac" + filename.txt + " >> filereversed.txt" )
```

*read the filereversed.txt from remote server and validate